# Check duplicates SQL or php?

Tags: php, sql

I have a field in my users database, a 6 digit number that is generated upon registration. I use `mt_rand(100000, 999999)` to generate the numbers.

Now to the question, to make sure no one gets the same number I need to either make the field UNIQUE (which i think seems the best) instead of some PHP code. Maybe theres some other way I don't know. The question is, whats the best way to do this?

Comment: auto_increment? Or create a random number and than select that number from the database and while it exist create a new number and input it?

Answer (score 2):

#### You can do this way using PHP.

First give a `unique` constraint to the field.

```
if (mysqli_errno() == 2027)
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO ... {mt_rand()}");
```

So, once you insert a duplicate value, it gives out an error code `2027`, saying duplicate. You can resubmit the query.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you

- use a nested select to get the max(user_id), increase it and use that value for the new user?
- create a table that holds just the current user-id and fetch, increase and use that value to create the new user?
- use an AUTO_INCREMENT column?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.

Performing a query to check if a generated number already exists is a bad solution and become worse with more and more users registered because more number are used, so you need to keep trace of all generated numbers to always generate a valid number.

With an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, this occurs *"automatically"* .